# invalid operation: s[k] (index of type *S)

Tags: methods, interface, go

I want to define a type like this:

```
type S map[string]interface{}
```

and I want add a method to the type like this:

```
func (s *S) Get( k string) (interface {}){
    return s[k]
}
```

when the program runs, there was a error like this:

```
invalid operation: s[k] (index of type *S)
```

So, how do I define the type and add the method to the type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type S map[string]interface{}

func (s *S) Get(k string) interface{} {
    return (*s)[k]
}

func main() {
    s := S{"t": int(42)}
    fmt.Println(s)
    t := s.Get("t")
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Output:

```
map[t:42]
42
```

Maps are reference types, which contain a pointer to the underlying map, so you normally wouldn't need to use a pointer for `s`. I've added a `(s S) Put` method to emphasize the point. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type S map[string]interface{}

func (s S) Get(k string) interface{} {
    return s[k]
}

func (s S) Put(k string, v interface{}) {
    s[k] = v
}

func main() {
    s := S{"t": int(42)}
    fmt.Println(s)
    t := s.Get("t")
    fmt.Println(t)
    s.Put("K", "V")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
map[t:42]
42
map[t:42 K:V]
```

Comment: maybe expound a bit on pointer vs value receivers, and why map can work with a value receiver?